# How to convert raw html from the web into parsable xml in Python

Tags: python, html, xml, python-3.x

I thought BeautifulSoup could do that, but it does not seem to do the trick.

What method have you already used, and is **long term reliable** ?

Comment: Did you try http://utidylib.berlios.de/ ? I don't know it, but Tidy is able to convert ugly HTML into sexy XML. Maybe its python wrapper can do it too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try http://utidylib.berlios.de/ , a python wrapper for tidy library.
Tidy works well in most cases.

For something more robust (or at least more browser-like), I guess you could try webkit or gecko. I'm not sure the wrappers responsible for cleaning HTML are available, but you can have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the lxml library, specifically [lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html) which gives you an ETree object which you can then serialize as XML with (amongst others) the .[tostring() method](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#serialisation).

If this fails on your HTML (it is too broken) you can use ElementSoup (an extension on BeautifulSoup) to build a lxml.html tree.